# Saving Data entered in gridview using c# and sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a form that has a asp.net gridview contained in it, on page load, I disabled some textboxes of the grid using jQuery.

[image]

my save method to the database is not working properly. I removed the grid from the "save" method and it works with the 2 textboxes.

```js
protected void saverecords() {

  try {
    int suc = 0;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    sqltrans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    string sqldelete = "delete from TrainEmpha where TrainCode = '" + txtcode.Text.ToString().Trim() + "'";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqldelete, conn, sqltrans);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comm.Dispose();

    string insertgroup = " Insert into TrainEmpha (TrainCode, TrainDesc,disreglev,EmphaLevel,Award1,Award2,Award3,Award4)" +
      " Values (@TrainCode, @TrainDesc,@disreglev,@EmphaLevel,@Award1,@Award2,@Award3,@Award4)";

    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in gridview.Rows) {

      string drplevel = ((DropDownList) gvr.FindControl("drp_grid_lvl")).Text.Trim();
      string txttrain = ((TextBox) gvr.FindControl("txttrained")).Text.Trim();
      string txtaward_1 = ((TextBox) gvr.FindControl("txtaward1")).Text.Trim();
      string txtaward_2 = ((TextBox) gvr.FindControl("txtaward2")).Text.Trim();
      string txtaward_3 = ((TextBox) gvr.FindControl("txtaward3")).Text.Trim();
      string txtaward_4 = ((TextBox) gvr.FindControl("txtaward4")).Text.Trim();

      comm = new SqlCommand(insertgroup, conn, sqltrans);

      comm.Parameters.Add("@TrainCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@TrainCode"].Value = txtcode.Text.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@TrainDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@TrainDesc"].Value = txtdescrip.Text.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@disreglev", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@disreglev"].Value = drplevel.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@EmphaLevel", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@EmphaLevel"].Value = txttrain.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@Award1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@Award1"].Value = txtaward_1.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@Award2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@Award2"].Value = txtaward_2.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@Award3", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@Award3"].Value = txtaward_3.Trim();

      comm.Parameters.Add("@Award4", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      comm.Parameters["@Award4"].Value = txtaward_4.Trim();

      suc += comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      comm.Dispose();
    }
    if (suc > 0) {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Notify", "alert(' RECORDS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!');", true);
      sqltrans.Commit();
    } else {
      lblDisplayErr.Text = "COULD NOT SAVE";
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually receiving an exception on the call to comm.ExecuteNonQuery(),  or are you receiving "COULD NOT SAVE" in your label?

Comment: I receive no message at all

Comment: If your method is actually getting called, if you are not getting any exceptions, then according to the code you posted, it should always run through the final test of (suc > 0) - therefore you should at least get "COULD NOT SAVE" in lblDisplayErr.Text - have you debugged the application and stepped through the code?

Comment: Ah - I just noticed that the code you posted is partial, and is inside an outer try block. You therefore must be receiving an exception which is jumping out of the try block.

Comment: Can you update your post with the full method code?

Comment: Also, you should investigate implementing the "using" structure, especially with your database connection object, the transaction object and your SqlCommand objects.Your code will look much nicer, and you do not need to call Dispose() manually. Also, you can shorthand your parameters additions, because the Add function returns the Parameter object. e.g. 
   comm.Parameters.Add("@TrainCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcode.Text.Trim();